# The background video is not displaying when i publish me site using github

Tags: html, css, github, web-development-server

the link to my website: https://waqqine.github.io/A-Cute-Girl-moving-background-website/

The link to my GitHub repository is : https://github.com/Waqqine/A-Cute-Girl-moving-background-website

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to the video with an absolute path:

```
<video src="/pexels-anna-nekrashevich-8056000.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
```

Change that to a relative path (either remove the initial `/` or make it `./`), and you're golden:

```
<video src="pexels-anna-nekrashevich-8056000.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Well, That actually worked thanks so much bro!